# How can I get the average cpu usage between the entry point of a method and the exit?

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter

I would like to get and log the average CPU usage between the entry point of a method and the exit of the method.

How can I achieve to get the average CPU usage via c# for such a scenario?

Comment: `GetThreadTimes`/realtime looks like the closest match, but look at http://blog.kalmbachnet.de/?postid=28 for its limitations.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you calculate/log the elapsed time in ms, as it gives a much more relibale number than *average cpu usage* which depends on too many things external to your code.

For elapsed millisceonds simply use `class StopWatch`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter` class for your task.